# Understanding oscillation frequency for SAF-C509 processor

Tags: automotive, 8051, oscillation

Good day.

For the time being, I'm reversing automotive ECU which has Intel51 architecture processor - SAF-C509 by Infineon/Simens. Its command exection part has 6 states with 2 phases for each state. Hence a single machine cycle is executed within 12 semi-phases.

One can add an external oscillator to set frequency of the processor. Lets assume that this frequency is 16MHz.

The user's manual on the processor says:

```
XTAL1 and XTAL2 are the output and input of a single-stage on-chip
inverter which can be configured with off-chip components as a Pierce oscillator.
The oscillator, in any case, drives the internal clock generator.
The clock generator provides the internal clock signals to the chip at half
the oscillator frequency.
These signals define the internal phases, states and machine cycles.
```

Now, I can't see in any obvious way what exactly is oscillated at that frequency. Is this `16MHz/2` frequency for semi-phases or something smaller?

Rephrasing the question: what's the frequency of machine cycles with 16MHz oscillator connected to the processor?

Comment: A 8051 machine cycle is 12 clocks. At 12MHz the machine cycle would be 1us. At 16MHz it would be 750ns.

Comment: You can measure the ALE signal, if external memory is used, to be sure.

Comment: @Kartman  Thanks for your response! So, when they refer to f_osc in the manual is it for the clock itself (the one connected to the processor) or for the machine cycles frequency? I wouldn't have asked about this if they had stated names explicitly somewhere in the manual. Oh, and the other thing here, where did the half-frequency got? I mean, the manual states `The clock generator provides the internal clock signals to the chip at half the oscillator frequency`. Is this halving for internal purposes and phases are clocked at the original oscillator frequency?